# Create file path from variables

Tags: python, path

I am looking for some advice as to the best way to generate a file path using variables, currently my code looks similar to the following:

```
path = /my/root/directory
for x in list_of_vars:
        if os.path.isdir(path + '/' + x):  # line A
            print(x + ' exists.')
        else:
            os.mkdir(path + '/' + x)       # line B
            print(x + ' created.')
```

For lines A and B as shown above, is there a better way to create a file path as this will become longer the deeper I delve into the directory tree?

I envisage an existing built-in method to be used as follows:

```
create_path(path, 'in', 'here')
```

producing a path of the form `/my/root/directory/in/here`

If there is no built in function I will just write myself one.

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Yes there is such a built-in function: [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.join('/my/root/directory', 'in', 'here')
'/my/root/directory/in/here'
```

Comment: Can this include the extension part of the file name? To end up with something like: `'/my/root/directory/in/here.ext'`

Answer (score 35):

You want the path.join() function from os.path.

```
>>> from os import path
>>> path.join('foo', 'bar')
'foo/bar'
```

This builds your path with os.sep (instead of the less portable `'/'`) and does it more efficiently (in general) than using `+`.

However, this won't actually create the path. For that, you have to do something like what you do in your question. You could write something like:

```
start_path = '/my/root/directory'
final_path = os.join(start_path, *list_of_vars)
if not os.path.isdir(final_path):
    os.makedirs (final_path)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use an object-oriented path with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (available as a standard library as of Python 3.4):

```py
from pathlib import Path

start_path = Path('/my/root/directory')
final_path = start_path / 'in' / 'here'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the os.makedirs() function. There is a good write-up [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-directory-in-python/).

Comment: this answer is useful, but not answering the question, and also a bit obvious. Thanks anyway. +1